# opacity in a div

Tags: html, css

I have the below page where the column header is fixed and the table body is scrollable. But when i scroll the    data, i have the result like the image 2. Please suggest as to what to do to get rid of this.  This is the code for my  div. The table is sitting inside the below div.

```
 <div style="overflow:auto; height:400px; position: absolute;">
```

Before scroll
[image]

After scroll
[image]

Comment: I don't see a question

Comment: Try giving those table header cells a background color, like white.  Perhaps you are, but there's not much to go off of.  If you add some of your HTML and CSS code, that related, that might help suggest a few things.  I worry there might be more issues than what I can see.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using a div in place of a table header row?

Comment: We could also use some css. A jsFiddle would be awesome.

Comment: I wanted a scrollable table with fixed header and this is what helped me achieve it. But Im not able to get rid of this prb. This is the Css for the table header class .formLabel {
  font-family : Arial;
  font-weight : bold;
  font-size   : 11px;
  align:center;
  text-align:center
  bgcolor:#FFFFFF 
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **have** to declare a background color, like this:

```
#element {
    background: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post a JsFiddle or Codepen of your markup.

The `bgcolor` attribute is deprecated. Use `background-color: #FFF` or `background: #FFF` instead. Also, please terminate your style declarations with a `;` you are going to experience strange issues otherwise. It also may be that you are not applying the style to that header row correctly, but it is difficult to say without some example markup.

Answer (score 0):

There's two odd things I'm noticing:

1) You are using a div tag as a table header, which I haven't seen anyone do nor do I see any obvious reason for it.

2) I heard position: absolute can cause some weird issues in IE. http://www.impressivewebs.com/absolute-position-css/ I'm not sure if that's the main issue though.